# What is Java JDKV2

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, I selected Xamarin Mobile Development as a component. All packages so far are acquired and applied in good time, but "Java JDKV2" has be acquiring for hours. I have a decent internet speed and i confirmed from task manager and resource monitor that the process is not frozen. I have checked Oracle's site and the Java Development Kit is under 200mb.

- I am asking what's in the "Java JDKV2" that Visual Studio is acquiring?
- Does anyone know it's exact size?
- Why is it taking so long?

Comment: Check this -> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52195/applying-jdkv2-hangs-up-visual-2017-installer.html ; good luck.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful thank you, but I saw this already, it hangs up his computer when it starts "applying". It has finally finished acquiring on my machine but I'm still curious to know what goes in it as the JDK on oracle's site would take mere minutes to download

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but hopefully helpful for all who are taken here via Google:

The Oracle homepage needs a cookie set before you can download the JDKV2. For some users it seems possible to open IE or Edge and set it there, in my case I needed to download the package manually.

See my answer here for complete details: [How to manually download components for the VS 2017 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808844/how-to-manually-download-components-for-the-vs-2017-installation/47808921#47808921)

The manual download should be faster than via the installer and can be put into a specific directory (something like C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages) for the installer to find.