# How to manually download components for the VS 2017 installation?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, failed-installation

While installing Visual Studio 2017 I encountered the error while downloading the JDKV2-Component for Xamarin (maybe someone could edit the English error message in?):

> Paket "JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.2,chip=x86" konnte von "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863182" nicht heruntergeladen werden.
>       Such-URL
>           https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=JavaJDKV2;PackageAction=DownloadPackage;ReturnCode=0x80072ee2
>       Details
>           WebClient-Download fehlgeschlagen: Timeout für Vorgang überschritten
>           Bits-Download fehlgeschlagen: Fehlerkontext: BG_ERROR_CONTEXT_REMOTE_FILE, Fehlercode: -2145844841
>           WinInet-Download fehlgeschlagen: Function: InternetOpenUrl, HR: -2147012894, Message: Unknown error 12002
>       Betroffene Workloads
>           Mobile-Entwicklung mit .NET (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat,version=15.0.27128.1)
>           Mobile-Entwicklung mit C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeMobile,version=15.0.27005.2)
>           Mobile-Entwicklung mit JavaScript (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebCrossPlat,version=15.0.27019.1)
>       Betroffene Komponenten
>           Android SDK-Einrichtung (API-Ebene 23) (globale Installation) (Component.Android.SDK23,version=15.0.27128.1)
>           Android SDK-Setup (API-Ebene 19 und 21) (Component.Android.SDK19,version=15.0.27128.1)
>           Android SDK-Setup (API-Ebene 22) (Component.Android.SDK22,version=15.0.27128.1)
>           Google Android-Emulator (API-Ebene 23) (globale Installation) (Component.Google.Android.Emulator.API23.V2,version=15.0.27128.1)
>           Java SE Development Kit (8.0.1120.15) (Component.JavaJDK,version=15.0.26403.0)

Same for the x64-version of the JDK.

It turned out that the Oracle-Website needs a License-Accepted-cookie to download the files. While Microsoft seemingly tried to add it to the download routine it doesn't work for me and the installation won't proceed beyond the point where it tries to install the JDK.

So I downloaded the files manually. **But where do I have to put them so that the Visual Studio installation knows that it won't need to download them again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching the web for some hours I finally found the solution here: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160625/packageidjavajdkv2packageactiondownloadpackageretu-5.html

Turns out you have to search for the following folder:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages

There you create a subfolder with the package name as written in the error message/error log (in my case "JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.2,chip=x86") and put the manually downloaded .exe file in there.

Restart the VS-installer and start the installation process.

Comment: Thank you for following up and posting an answer once you found the solution! This was helpful to me when having the same issue.