# Getting Error in Visual Studio 2017 when installing Xamarin Components-it says JDKV2 can not download

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

[image]

But when continue this and complete installation and open an android project then not getting any AndroidSDK. Is it happening for JavaJDKV2 or anything? I am not sure.

Comment: Finally , I solve this problem. The main problem occur when installing Xamarin Components. There was an error raised (image shown in the problem) when downloading JavaJDKV2 components.  It was happening because of my some network problem or internet problem when downloading this file. 
At last it download successful and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Oracle website demands a cookie for all downloads that (sometimes?) isn't set by the Visual Studio installer.

To circumvent this you can try to manually open the given link in your browser(s - I think the installer is using either Edge or Internet Explorer) and set the cookie by clicking the "Accept" radiobutton.

Or you could manually download the component and feed it to the installer like I explained here: [How to manually download components for the VS 2017 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808844/how-to-manually-download-components-for-the-vs-2017-installation/47808921#47808921)

Essentially you'd put the downloaded file into "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages" (or similar) in a directory named "JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.2,chip=x86" (or "JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.2,chip=x64"). The version number must be updated according to your downloaded file of course.